# Unix Server Protection from Physical Access?

Tags: security

I'm working to license our software to some buyer. Our software will be ran from an unix server that is physically controlled by the buyer.

Is there any way to prevent the buyer who have physical access to your server to access contents on the drive?

We want to protect our intellectual property because if the buyer steals our software, we won't have enough legal resources to pursue a claim internationally.

Comment: In short, no.  You can make it more difficult, but in the end, if you've got hold of a system, you control it.

Comment: Have you considered encryption of any sort?

Comment: Either the server has to have the key locally, or not.  If the former, the key can be recovered from the unencrypted FS; if the latter, then the service can't be restarted without remote assistance - which session can be intercepted.

Comment: Have you encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make it impossible. You can make it annoying or even hard, at best. But basically it comes down to the fact that physical access IS full access.

I've seen solutions where the server is psychically locked in a cage or where the usb ports are removed and HD's are locked in place with a padlock by holes drilled in the drive bay.

But if someone REALLY wants to steal it, they can, and thats why i recommend the contractual way instead (unless its a country like, say, China). Make them promise on paper that they wont and if they do, its an easy win in court and you don't waste a lot of resources trying to make something that will only delay a determined adversary.

Then there's the "making-it-look-like-an-appliance" approach. Like many firewalls, routers and even SAN systems are just a BSD or linux running underneath, the vendor has removed all normal login prompts and hidden the shells behind their own limited pseudo shell. But that requires extra resources.

Personally i wouldn't buy a system where the vendor tries to lock me out, if there was an alternative. I want to be able to fix anything in an emergency and not having to wait for support.

Comment: agree very much, physical access, it is impossible to be 100% protected. go with contract, or host it yourself.